# How Does the AddressOf operator work in VB.net when using a list in the below code snippet

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnByPrice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnByPrice.Click

    stockList.Sort(AddressOf CompareByPrice)



    stockList.Sort()
    DisplayList()


End Sub


Private Function CompareByPrice(x As Stock, y As Stock) As Integer
    If chkDescending.Checked Then
        Return y.Price.CompareTo(x.Price)
    End If
    Return x.Price.CompareTo(y.Price)

End Function
```

Comment: `AddressOf` is how you say that you want to make a reference to a routine (so that you can call it one or more times later) instead of trying to call it directly.  In the case of `Sort`, you're passing a reference to a comparison function, and then `Sort` will call that comparison function as many times as it needs to order the elements and complete the sort.

Answer (score 1):

The `AddressOf` operator creates a delegate, which is an object that refers to a method. That allows you to pass a method around like you would any other object and invoke it anywhere you like, even in places that have no direct reference to the object that the method is a member of.

The `List(Of T).Sort` method accepts a delegate to a method that has two parameters of type `T` and returns an `Integer` to indicate their relative magnitude. Any result less than zero is interpreted as the first object being less than the second, any result greater than zero is interpreted as the first object being greater than the second and a result of zero is interpreted as the two objects being equivalent.

Sorting is pretty much always done by comparing two items at a time and rearranging them if necessary, then repeating that over and over as required until the items are in order. The way that the items are chosen for comparison and rearranged will change based on the algorithm but the compare and rearrange step still exists.

Each time that `Sort` method needs to compare two items in the list, it invokes the delegate you provide and passes the two items in as arguments, then uses the result to decide whether to rearrange the items. That way, you can sort items of any type in any way you want without having to write your own sorting routine. The list itself already knows how to sort and you simply provide the specific comparison code and the list will use it, without having to care where it actually comes from.